# Poisson process, infinitesimal definition

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

How may I proceed with this problem:
Show directly from the infinitesimal definition of Poisson process that the first jump time $J_1$ of a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$ has exponential distribution of parameter $J_1$.

I have this definition:
Let $(X_t){t\geq 0}$ be an increasing, right-continuous integer-valued process starting from $0$. Let $0<\lambda<\infty$. $(X_t){t\geq 0}$ has independent increments and, as $h\downarrow 0$, uniformly in t,

$\mathbb{P}(X_{t+h}-X_t=0)=1-\lambda h +o(h)$,

$\mathbb{P}(X_{t+h}-X_t=1)=\lambda h +o(h)$

Comment: Consider the time interval in time segments of size $\delta$, where (approximately) either 0 or 1 arrival occurs (independently) in each segment.

Comment: For example, if you want to compute $P[Wait > t]$ then you can chop $t$ into $n$ segments, each of size $\delta = t/n$.